# How to select top 3 maximum values from SQL Server column

Tags: sql-server, max, repeat

I have values in SQL Server derived column sorted as descending i.e.

```
id   Count    OR     id   Count    OR     id   Count
1    4               1    5               1    11
2    4               2    2               2    1
3    4               3    1               3    1
4    4               4    1               4    1
5    4               5    1               5    1
```

Now I want to select top 3 maximum values. How can I select so that query returns consistent result every time.
For example if values of `Count` are same which `id`'s should be returned as top 3 maximums, similarly if 3rd value is matched with other values and if 2nd value is matched with other values then which `id`'s should be returned by the query. And the result should be consistent every time I execute the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The with ties argument of the top function will return all the of the rows which match the top values:

```
select top (3) with ties id, count from table1
order by count desc
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to return 3 values only, but make sure they are always the same 3 values, then you will need to use something else as a tie-breaker. In this case, it looks like your id column could be unique.

```
select top (3) id, count from table1
order by count desc, id
```